# Prevent java from handling path wildcards

Tags: java

I have a program where I have to take paths from the command line as input, likely with wildcards such as ?, * and **. Java persists in expanding these paths on it's own, usually screwing up.

For instance:

```
java -jar myapp.jar C:/Hello/World/*
```

Gives me a String[] args that looks like this:

```
["C:\Hello\World\foo", "C:\Hello\World\bar"]
```

Not only is this extremely troublesome, it also messes up the ** wildcard:

```
java -jar myapp.jar C:/Hello/World/**
```

Gives the same thing as before, when ** should be a recursive search. I have an algorithm for doing this efficiently, which I originally developed on python, but it's pointless if I can't use it. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

EDIT = I tried using different shells (PowerShell, cmd, eclipse), using different formats (no quotes, quotes, double quotes) and none of them worked.

Answer (score 5):

Java is not doing that, it's your shell.

Quote the arguments:

```
java -jar myapp.jar 'C:/Hello/World/**'
```

Or

```
java -jar myapp.jar "C:/Hello/World/**"
```

Comment: Using double quotes did the same thing (I tried that). Using single quotes ended up with the quotes going into string as well. I can make a work around for that at least, I guess.

Comment: Yes. Actually, I'm trying with both Powershell and Eclipse. Eclipse ignores the quotes and just puts everything in, Powershell recognizes the quotes and then the same thing as double quotes happens.

Comment: Wildcard expansion is not performed by the shell on Windows, it is performed by the application. (In fact, the shell doesn't even do command line argument splitting on Windows. The shell just gives the whole command line to the application, though libc usually takes care of splitting it up into an argv array for you.) My guess is that the JVM is trying to simulate UNIX-like behavior by doing pattern expansion for the application.

Comment: Makes sense. I used paths with wildcards on my python application on both Mac OS and Windows and nothing like this happened, so I assumed the problem was JVM being "helpful"

Comment: I always forget about how quirky the windows CMD shell is with the arguments. You're probably better of dealing with the single quotes - at least they'll work pretty much everywhere. (You won't get the single quotes in the string on Linux though.)

Comment: @elite5472 On Mac OS the shell should have done wildcard expansion, though this is easy to turn off with quoting. I have no idea how one disables the JVM's wildcard expansion on Windows. I'd assume that some sort of quoting/escaping would work, though based on your tests I don't know what sort of quoting would work. You might want to try testing  various quotes/escapes in plain old cmd just to rule out weirdness being caused by Eclipse or PowerShell.

Comment: Sorry, don't know anything about powershell (it just found it scary the few times I tried).

Comment: Okay, I pinned down the issue for the time being. It seems cmd doesn't see single quotes as string delimiters, so the result is a string enclosed by quotes. Powershell automatically expands both single and double quotes. It seems I am out of luck on this...

Answer (score 0):

This could be completely wrong, but try this:

`java -jar myapp.jar C:/Hello/World/\*`

Comment: Even if that worked(it doesn't) it wouldn't be user friendly.